# Resursive linking with rpath

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, portability, ld, rpath

I would like to create an executable (exec) that links a dynamic library (shared2) that links another shared library (shared1) such that I don't have to specify shared1 in the makefile of exec. Specifically, shared2 specifies -rpath to shared1, but when I compile exec, that rpath is evaluated relative to exec, not shared2. This required me to specify the -rpath to shared1 inside exec (which is what I want to avoid).

The following toy example illustrated my point:

Directory tree is:

```
Exec
    main.cpp
    makefile
shared2
    shared2
        shared2.cpp
        shared2.h
        makefile
shared1
    shared1.cpp
    shared1.h
    makefile
```

Exec/makefile

```
app: main.o
    g++ main.o -o app -L../shared2/shared2 -Wl,-rpath,../shared2/shared2 -lshared2 #-Wl,-rpath,../shared1

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -g -c -o main.o main.cpp -I../shared2/shared2

clean:
    rm -f app main.o
```

shared2/shared2/makefile

```
libshared2.so: shared2.o
    g++ -shared shared2.o -o libshared2.so -L../../shared1 -Wl,-rpath,../../shared1 -lshared1 

shared2.o: shared2.cpp
    g++ -fPIC -g -c -o shared2.o shared2.cpp -I../../shared1

clean:
    rm -f libshared2.so shared2.o
```

shared1/makefile

```
libshared1.so: shared1.o
    g++ -shared shared1.o -o libshared1.so

shared1.o: shared1.cpp
    g++ -fPIC -g -c -o shared1.o shared1.cpp

clean:
    rm -f libshared1.so shared1.o
```

I made main.cpp use something from shared2.cpp and something in shared2.cpp use something in shared1.cpp.

When I go to compile Exec/makefile, the rpath specified in shared2/shared2/makefile is evaluated relative to the location of Exec/makefile, and hence compilation fails. Note the bit that I have quoted out in the first makefile is what would be necessary for it to succeed, but I would like to avoid this.

Is there a workaround?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you care about Linux or Solaris, change this:

```
libshared2.so: shared2.o
    g++ -shared shared2.o -o libshared2.so -L../../shared1 \
        -Wl,-rpath,../../shared1 -lshared1
```

To this:

```
libshared2.so: shared2.o
    g++ -shared shared2.o -o libshared2.so -L../../shared1 \
       -Wl,-rpath,'$$ORIGIN/../../shared1' -lshared1
```

Note: the single quotes around `$$ORIGIN` are *required*.

Comment: Dear Employed Russian, Thank you for your answer. When I do as you suggested, when it compiles exec, I get /usr/bin/ld: warning: libshared1.so, needed by ../shared2/shared2/libshared2.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
../shared2/shared2/libshared2.so: undefined reference to `func1()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
I am running Ubuntu 12.04, g++ 4.8

Comment: What's the output of `ldd libshared2.so`?

Comment: @megavore Please note that the answer assumes you edit `Makefile`. If you execute the command directly, you need to replace `$$ORIGIN` with `$ORIGIN` (single `$` sign).